# Make bottom of the screen appear above keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I am developing a multiline `EditText` which has 3 lines. And the keyboard always appears below the cursor, but I want to always show the whole 3 lines even if I'm writing in the first one. So I need a way to put the bottom of the `view(screen/layout)` on the top of the keyboard.

Now I use a simple `EditText` with 3 lines and flag that is `multiline`.

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextMessage"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:hint="Message"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="3"
        android:maxLength="140"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:textColorHint="@color/JLGreyDarkSend"
        android:textSize="14sp">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to the activity.

Comment: I had AdjustPan, so that could cause my issue as well, thanks for advice for you and all the others who answered my question

Answer (score 2):

You can try to wrap your content into a ScrollView, that way it should push your layout up when using keyboard

Comment: I dont want to put the whole screen to scroll view but if other answers wont work i will be using your method. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to play with the [windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft). See [developer docs](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html) for more discussion.